# Bundler and Github Gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, rubygems, bundler

I'm confused ;-) I use Bundler which works fine for all my projects. In the recent project i need some Gems from Github so I've added

```
gem "dm-is-localizable", :git => "git://github.com/snusnu/dm-is-localizable.git"
```

to my Gemfile.

Bundle pushes the dm-is-localizable stuff into my project dir directly (same dir where app/, db/, lib/ etc. resist, so there's dm-is-localizable/ now). Whats going wrong there? Shouldn't Bundle put the stuff into vendor/?

Comment: Which bundler version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug with Bundle such that gems from :git don't get installed the same way as the rest. You can do `bundle install --system` to force all gems into be install into your system directory, or add these lines to your `.bundle/config` inside your project:

> BUNDLE_PATH: "vendor"

then run 'bundle install' once more.

I'm hoping Bundle will support :git more seamlessly in the future.